# Notify changes from generic database to WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, database, linq, entity-framework

Like in the title, I need to notify to my C# WPF application any changes in the database (there is another app adding data in one table).

I'm using Entity Framework and Linq. The dbms can be different (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL,...).

I am reading a lot about this and I ask it also here: is there a way yo reach this goal **without** using polling?

Comment: Yes, you have to listen to database events. But that requires very RDBMS-specific configurations and C# code. Which makes this subject far too broad. You could start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx).

Comment: There is for example change tracking feature in SQL Server 2008. Do you really need any changes to any table? And how would you process it consequently? Now the question is really too broad.

Comment: @GertArnold your link is only for SQL Server... I said for all dbms

Comment: @VDohnal also for your comment.. I said that dbms can be everything from rdbms world

Comment: That's why I said *start* here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the following link might help you, especially the answer for Event Notifications & Sql server's CLR objects(comments on Redis etc tools) for SQL Server but this may be limited to one or two databases:
[MsSQL callback function to asp.net website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366939/mssql-callback-function-to-asp-net-website)

For Oracle database, the ODP has similar notification mechanism:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/changenotification/ChangeNotification.htm

And since the EF providers are different for SQL & Oracle and with very less support for other database, you can have hosted service etc., listening to change notifications and publishing data change event so that the subscriber can take appropriate action like refreshing context or updating cache etc.

Comment: but your link are dbms-specific... does it exist something "universal"?

Comment: "Universal" is a tough phenomenon AFAIK :-) That's why I mentioned that its applicable to quite a few databases and also EF itself is not universal across most databases unlike other ORMs like NHibernate

Comment: @PieroAlberto But you can make service callback approach as a pattern so that whatever databases you work with has similar callback support can call into service to publish notification.

Comment: Ok, so, how can I do it with all database supported by EF? what do you mean with service callback?

Comment: @PieroAlberto Please take a look a bit more closely at the links provided, where the approach is you will host a web service and provide that service name to the database routine/proc where on data modification that proc will call the web service(this process I called as 'service callback'). I suggest pls take a look at Oracle ODP link, you can understand more on this.