# Expire C# in memory cache on data table value changes

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, caching

I have a c# app, which caches few data table in memory from sql server database.
I have written a thread to update the cache after 30 minutes, but that does not sounds a good solution.
I feel the best solution will be to expire cache on data table data change.
Is there any framework that does this by configuration.
I check Enterprise Cache Liberary but it does not seems to provide eye on data table.
Do I have to write trigger in database that will update a table that will help my thread to look into it and decide to expire the cache.

Please let me know the best practice for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for SqlDependency/SqlCacheDependency. Not very sure though. Check this link [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144344/Query-Notification-using-SqlDependency-and-SqlCach). It might be of use to you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this looks good, as I had written a thread to monitor database, I need to compare performance between my implementation and SQLDependency, how frequently it looks for changes, does it fire the same command and compare data in memory?

Comment: I don't think it looks for changes. In fact it notifies the client if there is a change in result for the registered query.

Comment: Yes it looks for changes, SQL does not notify Applicaiton, SQLDependency internally looks for changes to the log table after a configured time. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353558/how-does-a-sqlcachedependency-know-when-to-communicate-back-to-any-listeners-whe